# Font size adjustment

Tags: 14.04, display, fonts

When I booted my laptop today, something strange happened. It seams as if the font size of the System is changed to a extremely small one.

Titles of windows, the browser bar in Firefox, Terminal, just every thing is affected by this. I almost can't read anything anymore (fortunately the websites are displayed as usual).

I haven't changed any settings, but had some updates yesterday (just the normal Ubuntu update stuff).

Any idea what happened and how I can get my System back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Tweak Tool

-> Text scaling factor

Comment: did the trick (: Note: if someone else runs into this, you can download the `Unity Tweak Tool` in `Ubuntus Software-Center`, then you have to click on `Fonts` and there's the `Text scaling factor`